# Can't communicate between django and selenium docker containers

Tags: django, docker, selenium, continuous-integration

I'm trying to setup a CI environment where I can test my Django application with selenium where both are running in docker.

My test is setup with the following:

```py
from time import sleep
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

class MySeleniumTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    port = 8000


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver("http://selenium:4444", desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'})
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s:%s%s' % ('http://web', self.port, '/'))
        greeting = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("greeting")
        self.assertEqual(greeting.text, 'hello world')
```

I then try to run this on gitlab with this CI setup in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.26.2
  entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c']

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker build --tag django .

    - docker network create selenium-net
    - docker run -d --network selenium-net --name selenium selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-alpha-6-20200730
    - docker run --network selenium-net --name web --expose 8000 django dindselenium/manage.py test myapp
```

On my local machine the connection WebDriver setup succeeds but then Selenium fails to connect to the web app. On the CI environment I can't even connect to Selenium from the web app.

I've setup an example repo here: https://gitlab.com/oskarpersson/dind-selenium/, and an example of a failing job: https://gitlab.com/oskarpersson/dind-selenium/-/jobs/705523165